# ExecJS problem compiling Rails 3.1 assets

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, execjs

My Rails 3.1.rc4 app was working fine, but I'm trying to figure out the appropriate way to store my js files in the pipeline. If I put any code in a file other than application.js, I get the following error:

> Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-21
>   23:15:02 -0500 Compiled
>   ~/Dropbox/Rails/myapp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee 
>   (224ms)  (pid 69397) Error compiling asset application.js:
>   ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Reserved word "function" on line 1 
>   (in
>   /Users/micahalcorn/Dropbox/Rails/myapp/app/assets/javascripts/users/registrations.js.coffee)
>   Served asset /application.js - 500 Internal Server Error

This happens regardless of which file (`registrations` in this case) and claims a 'reserved word' regardless of the first word in the file (`var`, `function`, etc). I am using node.js as my runtime environment, and everything works fine if I remove coffeescript compiling gems and treat it like a Rails 3.0 app. I want to better understand the asset pipeline and follow conventions. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error

```
SyntaxError: Reserved word "function" on line 1
```

is a CoffeeScript compiler error. Either convert `function` to `->` in `registrations.js.coffee`, or rename it to `registrations.js` so that the file will be read as raw JavaScript.

Comment: I thought that I could mix raw js in with cs. Simple enough, thanks!

Comment: You can *kinda* mix raw JS in with CoffeeScript (by putting backticks around it), but it's usually not a good idea to do that. Instead, keep your JS in `.js` files and your CoffeeScript in `.js.coffee` files. Sprockets makes it easy to let the two languages coexist.

Comment: I don't understand. According to the CoffeeScript site: "You can use any existing JavaScript library seamlessly from CoffeeScript (and vice-versa)."

Comment: @DamianNowak Yes, but you can't mix JavaScript and CoffeeScript code in the same file. What the docs are saying is that CoffeeScript files can use objects/functions defined in JavaScript files, and vice versa.